# AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python

```
import pygame 
pygame.init()
```

I get this error

```
File "C:/Python34/game1.py", line 2, in <module>
     pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'Module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

Can't post code so here is an image 
https://s31.postimg.org/retln74zf/image.jpg

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Are you working with multiple files, or multiple files in diferent directories? If this is the scenario, don't forget to put an empty file called "__init__.py" inside the folder that you want to behave like a Python module

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/retln74zf/image.jpg

Comment: I was following a video on game development in pygame

Comment: import pygame
pgame = pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pgame.display.set_mode((800,600))

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/717ip827f/image.jpg

Comment: I still get the same error what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DiegoBernal Sure you don't have a file named `pygame.py` in the folder `C:/Python34/`? Move `game1.py` out of the folder it's currently in and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Felipe is on about.  `pygame.init()` returns a 2tuple of `(int, int)`, depending on the amount of successful and unsuccessful module initialisations.  It doesn't return anything that has pygame methods or modules on it.

Also, his comment about adding `init.py` is also incorrect, it's meant to be `__init__.py`, but even then is still irrelevant.

My guess is that you have your `game1.py` file in a funny place; within the python installation folder.  Try moving it to your Documents folder, and running it from there.  If that doesn't work, in the interactive interpreter, run:

```
import pygame
dir(pygame)
```

And post the results back here.

And please, when posting text, don't post a screenshot.  Copy the code, paste it here, select it all, and click the "{}" icon above the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following substitution, and follow the idea all along your code:

```
import pygame
pgame = pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pgame.display.set_mode((800,600))
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are saving the document into the "python27/site Packages/lib/pygame" the similar path you have in your system.

So that you will not get the error anymore.

focus on coding part now.

Thanks...